# Using "gonna" instead of "going to"

Tags: american-english, slang, contractions

> he did say he is **going to** be late

( I know this a correct )

But can I use instead of "is going to be late":

> he did say he is **gonna** be late

Answer (score 5):

*Gonna* is a non-standard spelling of *going to*. It represents the way most people actually say *going to* in rapid casual speech. You will encounter it frequently in texting, which values brevity and spontaneity over formal correctness, and you will occasionally find it employed jokingly or ironically to signal an extremely casual tone.

But *gonna* (and similar spellings like *hafta* or *oughta* or *useta*) should never be used in ordinary business or academic writing—in that sort of context it will be understood as [*eye dialect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect), portraying what is said as slovenly articulation or non-standard dialect.

Comment: We ***don't*** use "gonna, hafta, oughta" in formal/normal writing, but perhaps ***it's*** worth pointing out that most people accept *my* highlighted usages almost anywhere. That's contracted ***not*** and forms of ***to be***. Offhand I can't think of any others (particularly, that can be so concisely summarised). Can you add to my "summary of exceptions"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Contracted *have/has/had* and *will/would*?

Comment: My gut feel is that in any context where you felt comfortable contracting *have/has/had* and *will/would,* you would always be happy to do the same with *not* and *to be*. But the converse wouldn't *necessarily* apply. That's to say I think both these "contraction subgroups" are much less informal than *gonna, wanna, etc.*, but your suggestions are at least a *bit* more informal than mine. I also think those *-a = **to*** forms are often used by "narrators" in reported speech to suggest illiteracy rather than informality or "accurate transcription" as such, which rarely applies to our ones.